# amd radeon r9 series smp_affinity

Tags: opencl, fedora, gpgpu, amd-processor, softirq

Using taskset -c 1 with opencl program,it runs at the same speed that without use of it in four core machine. But the load with taskset is 13% without it 50%.

I am using AMD drivers 13.12 in fedora 20, after too much problems (amd r9 opencl not supported by fedora and AMD drivers does not compile, requires third part patch).

The system has 3 GPUs and I trying to assign interrupts of one GPU to one CPU core.
The problem is that I can not echo anything to smp_affinity in /proc/irq/60/

```
           CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3       
  0:        125          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      timer
  1:          3          3          2          2   IO-APIC-edge      i8042
  7:          1          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge    
  8:          0          0          1          0   IO-APIC-edge      rtc0
  9:          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   acpi
 14:      20553      19951      18934      23545   IO-APIC-edge      pata_atiixp
 15:          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      pata_atiixp
 16:        209        210        333        254   IO-APIC-fasteoi   snd_hda_intel
 17:          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   ehci_hcd:usb1, ehci_hcd:usb2
 18:          1          1          1          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   ohci_hcd:usb3, ohci_hcd:usb4, ohci_hcd:usb5
 40:          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      ahci
 41:          4          4          3          5   PCI-MSI-edge      xhci_hcd
 42:          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      xhci_hcd
 43:          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      xhci_hcd
 44:          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      xhci_hcd
 45:          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      xhci_hcd
 46:          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      xhci_hcd
 47:          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      xhci_hcd
 48:          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      xhci_hcd
 49:          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      xhci_hcd
 50:          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      xhci_hcd
 51:          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      xhci_hcd
 52:          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      xhci_hcd
 53:          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      xhci_hcd
 54:          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      xhci_hcd
 55:          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      xhci_hcd
 56:     260453         27      39686      10222   PCI-MSI-edge      p19p1
 57:         30         29         28         31   PCI-MSI-edge      snd_hda_intel
 58:         30         29         29         30   PCI-MSI-edge      snd_hda_intel
 59:         30         30         29         29   PCI-MSI-edge      snd_hda_intel
 60:     376820     387077     422262     414046   PCI-MSI-edge      fglrx[0]@PCI:1:0:0
 61:     233781     260237     282034     273928   PCI-MSI-edge      fglrx[1]@PCI:2:0:0
 62:     325068     337322     385699     381124   PCI-MSI-edge      fglrx[2]@PCI:3:0:0
NMI:        109        466        134        132   Non-maskable interrupts
LOC:    1455844    4537211    1861268    1830786   Local timer interrupts
SPU:          0          0          0          0   Spurious interrupts
PMI:        109        466        134        132   Performance monitoring interrupts
IWI:      48127      24519      17582      13174   IRQ work interrupts
RTR:          0          0          0          0   APIC ICR read retries
RES:   33436070   33287609   27497110   27413290   Rescheduling interrupts
CAL:       1727       1523       1401       1314   Function call interrupts
TLB:     416983     448396     436569     455603   TLB shootdowns
TRM:          0          0          0          0   Thermal event interrupts
THR:          0          0          0          0   Threshold APIC interrupts
MCE:          0          0          0          0   Machine check exceptions
MCP:         18         18         18         18   Machine check polls
```

```
Linux * 3.12.6-300.fc20.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Dec 23 16:44:31 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
display: :0.0  screen: 0                                                                                           
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.                                                                 
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon R9 200 Series                                                                   
OpenGL version string: 4.3.12618 Compatibility Profile Context 13.251                                              



display: :0.0  screen: 1                                                                                           
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.                                                                 
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon R9 200 Series                                                                   
OpenGL version string: 4.3.12618 Compatibility Profile Context 13.251                                              



display: :0.0  screen: 2
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon R9 200 Series                       
OpenGL version string: 4.3.12618 Compatibility Profile Context 13.251
```

It's possible to assign IRQ 60 to core 0, 61 to 1 and 62 to 2 ?
Or reduce CPU load.

Comment: can be solved with sdk 2.9 and 13.25 (beta driver)

Comment: The problem is in the SDK, ensure to remove /etc/ld.so.conf.d AMD file, that links to obsolete libOpenCL